# Displaying Date wise values but i want to display values added day by day

Tags: mysql

I Coded This Code:

```
SELECT invoice.Date AS Inv_Date, COUNT(*) AS NoOfInv, SUM(Total) AS Inv_SumNetTotal 
FROM invoice 
WHERE invoice.Date BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y-%m-01') AND DATE_FORMAT(LAST_DAY(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH),'%Y-%m-%d')
GROUP BY invoice.Date
UNION ALL
SELECT  invoice.Date AS Inv_Date,COUNT(*) AS NoOfInv, SUM(Total) AS Inv_SumNetTotal 
FROM invoice 
WHERE invoice.Date BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-01') AND DATE_FORMAT(LAST_DAY(NOW()),'%Y-%m-%d')
GROUP BY invoice.Date;
```

to output the data for line chart

I want to display Inv_SumNetTotal addding one to one day by day

```
NoOfInv  Inv_Date       Inv_SumNetTotal
104  2024-01-01 **286720**
248  2024-01-02 **720102**
208  2024-01-03 **765290**
231  2024-01-04 820294.6
216  2024-01-05 1032960
185  2024-01-06 643782
206  2024-01-07 483792
205  2024-01-08 678784.5
213  2024-01-09 485897.5
42   2024-01-10 190024
2    2024-02-09 410
2    2024-02-10 9960
```

this is my output

But I want to display added value like this

```
NoOfInv  Inv_Date       Inv_SumNetTotal
104  2024-01-01 **286720**
248  2024-01-02 **1,006,822**
208  2024-01-03 **1,772,112**
```

Answer (score 0):

use this approach

SELECT
Inv_Date,
NoOfInv,
SUM(Inv_SumNetTotal) OVER (ORDER BY Inv_Date) AS Cumulative_Inv_SumNetTotal
FROM (
SELECT
invoice.Date AS Inv_Date,
COUNT(*) AS NoOfInv,
SUM(Total) AS Inv_SumNetTotal
FROM
invoice
WHERE
invoice.Date BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y-%m-01') AND DATE_FORMAT(LAST_DAY(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH), '%Y-%m-%d')
GROUP BY
invoice.Date

UNION ALL

SELECT
invoice.Date AS Inv_Date,
COUNT(*) AS NoOfInv,
SUM(Total) AS Inv_SumNetTotal
FROM
invoice
WHERE
invoice.Date BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-01') AND DATE_FORMAT(LAST_DAY(NOW()), '%Y-%m-%d')
GROUP BY
invoice.Date
) AS combined_results;

This query uses the window function SUM(Inv_SumNetTotal) OVER (ORDER BY Inv_Date) to calculate the cumulative sum of Inv_SumNetTotal for each row based on the order of Inv_Date. The result is displayed as Cumulative_Inv_SumNetTotal.

Now, when you run this query, you should get the desired output with the accumulated values for Inv_SumNetTotal. Adjust the column names or formatting as needed for your specific use case.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear why you are using UNION. Your current query is doing `(beginning to end of last month) UNION ALL (beginning to end of current month)`. Surely, `beginning of last month to end of current month` would make more sense?

You can use `SUM()` as a [window function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html) to calculate the cumulative sum:

```sql
SELECT
    invoice.Date AS Inv_Date,
    COUNT(*) AS NoOfInv,
    SUM(Total) AS Inv_SumNetTotal,
    SUM(SUM(Total)) OVER (ORDER BY Date) AS Inv_CumSumNetTotal
FROM invoice 
WHERE invoice.Date BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y-%m-01')
                       AND LAST_DAY(NOW())
GROUP BY invoice.Date
```

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_SA0xI48).